# Maven and Eclipse, war appears as a jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, jboss

I have a problem with maven and my eclipse (helios).
I have created a war project with maven like this:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=net.myproject.front -DartifactId=personnes-front -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

Maven have created all the directories arborescence and the pom is for a war project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.myproject.front</groupId>
    <artifactId>personnes-front</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>personnes-front Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
</project>
```

When I run a mvn clean install command, a war is created by maven.

Now, in my eclipse, my project appears as a jar and I can deploy it in my jboss 6. Jboss 6 is integrated in eclipse by the jboss tools.

I don't understand why my project appears as a jar for eclipse.

Someone can help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: What Maven Plug-in do you use?

Comment: Just the eclipse plugin to generate eclipse settings

Comment: @Kiva - are you using m2eclipse plugin?

Comment: Yes, it's installed with jboss tools. why this question ?

Comment: run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` in the folder where your pom.xml is located. Then refresh the eclipse project to see if that fixed it.

Comment: also right-click on the project-> uMaven ->update project configuration.  I've found m2eclipse and eclipse can get confused somethimes since the eclipse builder works seperately than a Maven build does.

Comment: @CoolBeans I did that to generate my project eclipse. I forgot to write it. So, to generate my eclipse project, I did this command ;)

Comment: Wonderful BuffaloBuffalo, your advise is good. My problem is corrected :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert the project into a Dynamic Web Project (Eclipse Web Tools Project - WTP) you need to have Eclipse Java EE edition, or have installed the WTP plugin.
Assuming this is already the case, you need to define the eclipse plugin in your pom

```
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8</version>
      <configuration>
      <wtpversion>1.5</wtpversion>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

When using the m2eclipse, you should update your project configuration by right-clicking on the project and select "Maven - Update project configuration". That should generate the necessary eclipse meta files (located in the hidden .settings folder) to help Eclipse interpret this project as a web project (using the WTP plugin - Dynamic web project).

When not using the m2eclipse, running mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse from a command prompt will also generate those meta files in .settings, causing eclipse to see it as a dynamic web project.

See the eclipse plugin page for more info : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/plugin-info.html